# WPF Button Visibility issue

Tags: wpf, button, visibility

I have  this binding on Visibility

```
Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
```

I want to set `Visibility = False` if `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility = True` and `Visibility = True` if `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility = false`

Is there something like this:

```
Visibility="!{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
```

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Hasan's point, the converter here is pretty simple:

```
public class VisibilityInverterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is Visibility)
        {
            var vis = (Visibility) value;

            if (vis == Visibility.Hidden || vis == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error : Set property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Path' threw an exception.

Code: Visibility="{Binding Path={TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityInverter}}" >